# How do you install the xlrd package on a mac?

Tags: python, pip, xlrd

I am trying to install the `xlrd` package on my mac to use in Python 3.5.4 to be able to read excel documents.

I have opened 'Terminal' and typed:

```
pip install xlrd
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking xlrd
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement xlrd
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for xlrd
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Elizabeth/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Run `pip -V` and check what Python version it outputs. Does it match Python 3.5.4?

Comment: Have you checked the debug logs at */Users/Elizabeth/.pip/pip.log*? It maybe a network (proxy, SSL) issue, because I can install it fine on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ xlrd
```

Most common issue is pip not connecting to the simple index via SSL. Post your debug log to confirm this. Pip is also probably outdated, so to update it try:

```
sudo pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip
```